# how to match var/id to class

Tags: jquery, class, match

I'm new to jquery and, in addition, I think I'm having a brain freeze.

I have a number of links with different ids. I want to match the clicked link with a div with the corresponding class so the div will show/hide/toggle as appropriate.

I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.folioBox').hide();

 $('a.interface').click(function(){
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        var currentBox = $('.folioBox .' + currentId);

        $(currentBox).toggle(400);

        });
});
</script>


<a class="interface" id="apple">Apple flavor</a>
<a class="interface" id="banana">Banana flavor</a>
<a class="interface" id="cherry">Cherry flavor</a>

<div class="folioBox apple">content</div>
<div class="folioBox banana">content</div>
<div class="folioBox cherry">content</div>
```

I just can't get it to work and I can't figure out whether I would be best using match or find or filter.

Some assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("a.interface").click(function() {
  $("div.followBox." + this.id).toggle(400);
  return false;
});
```

No need to make it more complex than that. If there are multiple matches, then they'll all be toggled.

**Note:** I've made the click handler `return false` so stop the link being followed. Depending on what you have in the `href` attribute, the page may actually being refreshed, which explains why it appears not to be working.

Comment: thanks cletus! i knew there had to be a more elegant way of doing something so simple! duh.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at it now but have you tried doing a return false at the end because you are hitting an anchor?

let me know if that works and i'll stop debugging this end.

**EDIT**

Get rid of the space between the two classes.

```
var currentBox = $('.folioBox.' + currentId);
```